# deleting ubuntu from internal ssd with no other operating system

Tags: delete

I have had my ssd repalced in my macbookpro 2007. So it was blank....i made a bootable external disk with ubuntu on it and booted mac up on it, and installed it on the hard drive. i want to delete and put osx back. How do  go about doing this. Cant seem to delete ubuntu.

Comment: The OS X installer should give you the option to format the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Just go about installing the OSX, you will get the delete options where you create partitions or modify disk in OSX installer.

Comment: Thanks for reply...i have no osx on the mac. It has a brand-new ssd in it. i have put on ubuntu from a bootable drive onto the mac. so it only has ubuntu on it. Have tried booting it from a high sierra bootable osx on a memory stick but doesn't work.

Comment: Please go through this link https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/clean-install-macos-3637409/ see if you are missing something. I can't help any further since I don't have a mac system.